# Can't find syntax error in SQL nested select

Tags: mysql, sql

I seem to can't find the syntax error in my sql select statement. Been staring at the screen for a couple of hours now and got nothing. Plz help.

The Error is #1064, and its saying that the syntax error is "near 'EXISTS (SELECT e.item_Backid FROM Rental'".

Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.item_Backid, inv_name, item_size, item_Frontid, 
item_modeltype 
FROM Item a, Inventory c, Status b 
WHERE a.inv_id = c.inv_id and a.stat_id = b.stat_id and a.loc_id = 1 and 
     (a.stat_id = 1 or a.stat_id = 7) and 
      a.item_Backid NOT EXISTS (SELECT e.item_Backid 
                                FROM Rental d, Reserve1 e 
                                WHERE d.rent_id = e.rent_id and 
                                     (d.request_date = :cust_request_date or 
                                      d.request_date >= :cust_due_date or 
                                      d.due_date <= :cust_request_date))
ORDER BY inv_name, item_modeltype, item_Backid;
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `NOT IN` ?

Comment: `<column name> NOT EXISTS` is not valid syntax.  I'm not sure how much clearer the error could be.

Comment: BTW, it's generally better to write `a.stat_id IN (1, 7)` instead of using `OR`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff no need to be snarky. this person could easily be new to SQL and the error message doesn't explicitly say "NOT EXISTS is invalid syntax" it just says thats where the problem is near. even a SQL god such as yourself was a newbie at one point, show some grace for other beginners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL is not correct.

The format for `NOT EXISTS` is

```
SELECT <columns> FROM <table1>
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT <columns> FROM <table2>);
```

Please refer to the following link for explanation
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Your query would work with `NOT IN`

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.item_Backid, inv_name, item_size, item_Frontid, 
item_modeltype 
FROM Item a, Inventory c, Status b 
WHERE a.inv_id = c.inv_id and a.stat_id = b.stat_id and a.loc_id = 1 and 
 (a.stat_id = 1 or a.stat_id = 7) and 
  a.item_Backid NOT IN (SELECT e.item_Backid 
                            FROM Rental d, Reserve1 e 
                            WHERE d.rent_id = e.rent_id and 
                                 (d.request_date = :cust_request_date or 
                                  d.request_date >= :cust_due_date or 
                                  d.due_date <= :cust_request_date))
ORDER BY inv_name, item_modeltype, item_Backid;
```